# Long polling on a penny auction site?

Tags: long-polling

On a penny auction site, there are a few fundamental requests that happen over time, namely:

- Bidding request (when someone places a bid)
- Timer updates
- Leading bidder updates

I am trying to understand long polling a bit better and I'm stuck with this. As far as i know, Long polling is there to reduce Ajax requests. I.e. By only having ONE for visual updates, and ONE for actions. So, therefore:

1. bidding request (to place bids) will remain as is, but all the visual update requests will be combined into one "long poll" request, right?
2. If the user connects to the site for the first time, he will request the current state of the page by also passing in what he was last told the state of the page was. The server will compare it with the state of what it should be, and if they are different, it will pass the new state back to the user, correct?
3. When passing the state back, the LONG POLL will effectively stop, the screen will be updated, and a new LONG POLL will be started, correct?

Is this understanding correct so far?

If that is so, how will this in any way decrease the number of requests to the backend if the server still has to compare the state?

How will this help if the page is opened in 50 different windows by one user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long polling is used  to simulate a connection in which the server pushes data to the client (rather than what is actually happening - which is the client requesting the information from the server). Basically the client requests data from the server, but rather than returning data to the client immediately the server 'holds' the request open - it can then return data to the client at a later time point - which can be used to simulate the server updating the client in 'real time'.

So in your example of an auction site the client might long-poll the sever for an item bid amount - the server would hold this request open, and when the bid value on that item changes can return the updated amount to the client.. this can be used to give the impression of the server updating the client as the bid amount changes.

As far as requests to the server go, this very much depends on how this is implemented. Obviously using long polling will reduce the number of requests made to the server compared with, say, getting the client to issue a new 'standard' request every second to check for updates. Multiple instances of the client will still result in multiple requests to the server - and moreover the server still has to deal with the overhead of holding the long polling requests open and responding to these when appropriate.. Apparently different servers, and server architectures, deal with this more effectively than others.

Comment: But what about something like synching the time with the server? Every couple of seconds the client WILL have to know what the auction time is (as with penny auctions it might increase etc) ?

Comment: In that case you could have the server update the client (by sending a response to the long poll request) when the server sees that the relevant auction time has increased.